# Solving factorial inequality

Tags: inequality, induction, factorial

> a) Use mathematical induction to prove that
>   $$(1)(1!)+(2)(2!)+(3)(3!)+...+(n)(n!)=(n+1)!-1,$$
>   where n $\in  \Bbb Z^+$.
>
> b) Find the minimum number of terms of the series for the sum to exceed $\ 10^9$.

I was able to do part $a$, so I proved it for $n$. However, I actually don't know part $b$. How to solve an inequality with a factorial? Thank you for helping in advance.

Comment: It's really not that hard with trial and error and a pocket calculator....

Comment: Where is the inequality?

Comment: This [OEIS page](https://oeis.org/A000142) lists the first few terms of the factorial sequence, starting with $n = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that factorial function is an increasing function.

Hence solving $(n+1)!-1>10^9$ can be done for example by using bisection search.